# matplotlib - how to draw a new plot in a loop in the same window

Tags: matplotlib

I use the below code. This comes up with three different windows. I would like the plot to show up in the same window. Any ideas?

Thanks

--
ps: clarification. I would like to see the curve of y[0] vs x[0] first then it erased and see y[1] vs x[1] and then it erased and see y[2] vs x[2]. Right now it is showing all three with three different colors. See second chunk of code.

--

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3]
plt.ion() # turn on interactive mode, non-blocking `show`
for loop in range(0,3):
    y = numpy.dot(x, loop)
    plt.figure()   # create a new figure
    plt.plot(x,y)  # plot the figure
    plt.show()     # show the figure, non-blocking
    _ = input("Press [enter] to continue.") # wait for input from the 



import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

x = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
y = [[1,4,9], [16,25,36], [49,64,81]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.ion()
plt.show()
for i in range(3): 
    ax.plot(x[i],y[i])  # plot the figure
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    _ = input("Press [enter] to continue.") # wait for input from the
```

Comment: First, you can add the keywor argument `block=False` in `plt.show()`. Second, you are creating a new figure every time you call `plt.figure()`. To add a new plot just use `plt.plot()` without refering to the figure. I am not sure about the `input()`, but it is worth considering matplotlib events or widgets for triggering the plot update, as they still work with `plt.show()`. Lastly, to update the figure you can call `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()`.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn’t work. Shows three different figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you with the problem. Notice the use of plt.show() outside the loop. `plt.show()` starts an event loop, checks for the currently active figure objects, and opens a display window.

```
import numpy
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.ion()
plt.show()
for loop in range(0,3): 
    y = numpy.dot(x, loop)
    line,=ax.plot(x,y)  # plot the figure
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    line.remove()
    del line
    _ = input("Press [enter] to continue.") # wait for input from the
```

Comment: Are you doing it in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Use `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: Thank you. In the question, I have added new code for clarification. I am looking for three separate graphs but this shows three graphs in one window in three colors.

Comment: You can delete the line by first defining it, and then invoking `line.remove()`